# Toggling sort order of listviews in jQuery Mobile

Tags: listview, sorting, jquery-mobile

I'm hacking up a prototype app using jQuery Mobile (aka JQM). I'm no expert, but I'm getting by until hitting a sorting challenge.

I want a selection of data rows and need the rows to be sortable based on various attributes. Typical attributes are name, date, value, etc.

I've found and installed the jQuery Mobile Tiny Sort plugin by Andy Matthews (at http://andymatthews.net/code/jqm-tinysort). Using this I have been able to get the listview to sort on the attributes.

The problem is that this is only allowing ascending sorts. I need to be able to toggle between the different attributes, but also toggle between ascending and descending sorts.

The above plugin is based on the jQuery Tiny Sort plugin (from http://tinysort.sjeiti.com) and this is able to do the toggle.

What I am looking for is the correct way (if it is possible at all) to pass the asc/desc parameters through from the JQM plugin to the backend Tiny Sort plugin.

Has anyone any ideas on how to do this? Or is there a better approach I should adopt?

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straightforward to modify Andy Matthew's plugin to support bi-directional sorting as the actual sorting is done by the Jquery tiny sort plugin.

Firstly, modify the script 'jquery.jqmts.js' by adding a new 'sortOrder' option with a default value of 'asc' or 'desc'.
Secondly locate the call to .tsort method passing the additional sort parameter

```
$('li:not(.' + options.className + ')', $el).tsort({ data: 'sort-' + e.currentTarget.value, order:options.sortOrder });
```

This option can now be set on a case-by-case basis any time that you call the .jqmts plugin.